# Проблема при добавлении списка в словарь

Tags: python

При добавлении списка в словарь, двузначные числа делятся на отдельные цифры.
Например:

```
dic = {}
dic[1] = list('10')
```

вывод:

```
{'1':['1','0']}
```

А ожидается

```
{'1':['10']}
```

Почему так происходит и есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
dic = {}
dic[1] = ['10']

print(dic)
```

А происходит так, потому что так работает конструктор `list` с 1 параметром, который воспринимается как итерируемый объект.

Дока https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list

Answer (score 2):

Двузначные числа делятся на отдельные цифры, т.к. строка преобразовывается в список и каждый символ становится отдельным его элементом.

Делайте вот так:

```
dic[1] = ['10']
```